# Using Swagger in Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, swagger

I am new in Swagger and as far as I see it is used to generate API documents autotomatically. In addition to that, I think it is also used to generate frontend by using Swagger Codegen. AT this step, I am confused regarding to using swagger in my project properly.

I have created my backend using .NET Core and API methods are ready. Now, I need to integrate swagger to my project. I have an initial Angular frontend app, but as the code is mixed, I want to create frontend from stratch and then integrate Swagger to it. So;

**1.** Should I generate frontend using necessary Swagger tools? It does not seems to be good, but if it is used generally and will not be a problem as the project gets bigger, of  course I can use that option.

**2.** If I create the Angular project from stratch, how can I integrate the swagger? Should I generate code by using the ts files of the related components?

**3.** If I add a new component to the frontend and corresponding API methods to the API where Swagger is already used. Which modification ahould I made? I gave a try and it geneartes a new swagger config file after building the project.

Comment: I don't think you have a clear understanding what swagger is... Its OpenApi which is basically a tool to describe a REST api. It has nothing to do with frontend or angular. Now there are tools online like swashbuckle or nswag https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag that automatically generate a frontend app for you based on the api specification. They can also generate the OpenApi/swagger specification based on your net core project.

Comment: So the workflow i've used is: create an asp net core application. Then I integrate NSwag, which generates the api document (swagger.json for example) based on my .net core controllers. Then i use the NSwag toolchain again to generate REST api clients in typescript, which i then place in my Angular project. Then i can easily call a rest service/client from angular.

Comment: @sommmen Thanks for help. You are right, I am a little bit confused and need to be clarified. So, I need a tool or library that let me generate api documents automatically. I think I can use Swagger for this aim. On the other hand, I am confused about the 3 points above. Could you please clarify me?

Comment: the best way is to head on over to https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag and create a little sample project. Download the tool that comes with nswag, and just check out the options for code generation.

Comment: @sommmen Very good explanations. Could you confirm these issue please? **1)** As far as I understood, we can integrate Swagger and then test our API methods via Swagger page after running the backend. There is no need to use swashbuckle or nswag at this step? **2)** After that I can use NSwag for automatically generating a frontend app. But, at this step, will it create cpomponent with html and ts files? And do you suggest to use this approach with the genareted components? **3)** What did you mean with "They can also generate the OpenApi/swagger specification based on your net core project"

Comment: posted an answer for you. Since there are so many unknows for you still i highly recommend you fire up a test project and just spend a day or so figuring out what works for you and your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going off on the comments I made below the question.

Just to clarify what swagger and openApi is, swagger is both a rest api specification (e.g. swaggerSpec.Json) and a set of tools to deal with the specification. For example, swagger codegen, swagger UI etc. Now at some point in time, the specification was renamed from swagger to OpenApi.

This means the specification is called OpenApi and swagger is a set of tools to deal with openApi.

Source: https://swagger.io/blog/api-strategy/difference-between-swagger-and-openapi/

Aside from swagger, there are a set of alternative tools like NSwag and Swashbuckle that can make working with the openApi specification easier.

There are 2 main parts:

- Code generation for the openApi specification. You can generate code for the server (e.g. ASP.NET core rest controllers) from an OpenApi document and clients (e.g. C# rest clients, .TS rest clients, java you name it) from the OpenApi document. Or you can just generate the OpenApi specification (my SwaggerSpec.json) itself from e.g. your .net core project with some tooling.
- (Web)Ui to easily host documentation. Swagger has webUI, NSwag, and even alternative tools like https://github.com/Redocly/redoc All of these include a way to easily test the Api endpoints you define. Generally these documentation sites are standalone things. They maybe configured style-wise but you generally leave them untouched. You can ofcourse roll your own - or clone any ui repos and alter that - but thats another topic.

I've investigated all 3 options (Swagger, SwashBuckle and NSwag) and i opted for NSwag because at the time a) it was the one i got working and b) it had the most features and c) the community was fairly active. This was about a year ago.

I shall explain my workflow and this should answer most questions you have. I feel like this Question is getting rather broad, so please do some digging around and try to get more specific questions tailored to your needs.

Like i said i use the NSwag toolchain:

1. I create Asp.Net controllers in my server app.
   This contains some attributes to controller functions/endpoints so the swagger specification gets generated better:
   [image]
2. I then use NSWag studio to create an openApi document file

[image]

Output:
[image]

3. At this point you could opt to use NSwag *again* to generate for example a typescript client which you can then use in your angular/react w/e frontend project:

[image]

4. I then add the swagger document to my asp.net server project, and enable the swagger UI:

Somewhere in Startup.cs:

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettingsAccessor, ILogger<Startup> logger, StaticFileConfigSection staticFileConfig)
        {
            // Add the openApi document and serve the swagger dashboard.
            app.UseOpenApi();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3(); // serve Swagger UI 
         ...
```

And I can then go to /swagger to see the web ui:

[image]

And that's it. All these tools can be automated ofcourse - but i opted not to. Getting that to work can be a hassle and with NSwag studio i was always a button click away anyways. And this forced me to be more careful with my work.

Comment: Many thanks for all of your detailed helps, voted up ;) That helped me so much and before proceeding I also need to make a choice and I little bit confused. Because, as far as I see, NSwag and Swagger are not the same. But Swagger seems to be more popular. So, can I use Swagger to cretae API documents and generate Angular frontend code?

Comment: On the other hand, do you have any idea to split the generated code to multiple ones? Because as the project is getting bigger, using all the generated code on a simngle file will be a big problem. Any idea about that?

Comment: @Jack Use whatever you like - also see the MSDN documentation for asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.1 . For code generation, NSwag always has the clients marked as partial: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CSharpClientGenerator so you can extend the class like that. Im not sure about the other toolchains

Comment: Do you mean splitting issue with the toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using Codegen is your choice. You can use the generated code as a boilerplate to have a straight start with your API integration. You may just copy the generated models and services and integrate them. It will save you a lot of coding time and also avoid human error in the coding of the services. But the rest of the frontend can be anything you like, not necessarily the generated project. You may use for example an Angular seed of choice and just integrate the services from Codegen.
2. As I've mentioned, you can copy the generated services and models from Cogeden, to have a head start. If you decide to go fully manual, you'll have to use Angular HTTP to make the requests to the server (https://angular.io/guide/http). You have to manually define the models and the services to operate with the entities. Swagger will only be a reference for the API in this case, no integration at all with Angular. I discourage this option unless the library generated by Codegen is insufficient. If the Swagger design is properly done (which sadly is uncommon to see), following all the standards and providing complete data models, you can trust the generated library.
3. This is advice and not objective guidance: if the updates to the API are minor, make them directly in your code and keep your Swagger updated with the new changes. If the changes are relevant, you need a new major API version, with a different endpoint. In that case, generating a new Swagger Codegen library and placing it in place of the old one will be a good idea. To be able to do this, you must avoid modifying the internals of the services of the generated library, using the library as much "as-is" as possible.

Comment: Many thanks, voted up.On the other hand, do you have any idea to split the generated code to multiple ones? Because as the project is getting bigger, using all the generated code on a simngle file will be a big problem. Any idea about that?